# How to save and load a splinefun object in R?

Tags: r, spline, r-package

I have been using the `splinefun` function in `R` to create a smooth interpolation between some data `x` and `y`. For example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
f <- splinefun(x, y)
f(seq(1, 10, by = 0.1))
```

Now assume that obtaining `y` from `x` is time-consuming. The two highly-related questions are:

1. How can I save and load the function `f` from one `R` session to another *without* re-evaluating (or re-reading from a table) `x` and `y`?
2. How can I include `f` as part of an `R` package *without* evaluating/reading in each load `x` and `y`?

I know that this changed from `R 3.0.0` and now `f` is saved inside a specific environment

```
environment(f) # <environment: 0x1036daf80>
```

and has the bytecode `<bytecode: 0x1036e0748>`, but no idea what to do with that.

Comment: You can use a physical cash decorator. The name of the cache will be a hash of the function argument (here the function is splinefun abd arguments are `x` and `y`)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Sorry, but I am not sure to understand what do you mean... Probably because my programming knowledge outside `R` is definitely limited. Could you elaborate on how to make this implementable in `R`?